# Htaccess same rule for 2 files not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create friendly pagination using htaccess file.

But its not working I guess I am using wrong rule for files.

Check out my codes below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/$ search/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/$ search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ new.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ cat.php?id=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ cat2.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Everything is working fine, only `cat2.php` is not working.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the order around between your 2 cat rules. `(.*)` matches everything, including slashes, so it will always match whatever cat2 matches. Try just swapping their orders and include `L` flags:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/$ search/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/$ search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ new.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ cat2.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ cat.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC]
```